# Can I install oracle linux or debian in Sun enterprise m4000 sparc?

Tags: linux, solaris, oracle, sun, sparc

I would like to install a linux OS on this server but after trial and error always came back with a error, i know that the installation is fully compatible with SPARC architecture, every time i used oracle linux, debian, gentoo...
After i boot cdrom the cd starts to run in all cases then when it is charging in memory, an error always come.
Is it compatible with linux?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Sun Enterprise M4000 is a not-so-old Fujitsu sparc64 CPU. Debian only claims to support sun4u and sun4v CPUs:  https://www.debian.org/ports/sparc/  Depending on the distribution, you may not have supported hardware.  What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Trap : Division by Zero for Debian and oracle linux 6.9,

Comment: freebsd cpr red_state reset

Comment: Are you using SPARC Debian and Oracle Linux installation disks?  Because I can't find Oracle Linux for SPARC in any format, and the [Oracle Linux HCL](https://linux.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=117:1) doesn't seem to have any SPARC servers in it.

Comment: i downloaded this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/linux/downloads/oracle-linux-sparc-3665558.html

Comment: You may have a hardware problem then.  Does the server boot properly from a *Solaris* SPARC install disk?  See the "Fault Isolation" portion:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19580-01/819-2210-14/819-2210-14.pdf

Comment: For the image you downloaded, where there any notes/readme for the M4000 being supported or requiring a specific FW level?

Comment: The "Linux for SPARC" release from 2015, which was based on Oracle Linux 6, was explicitly for `sun4v` machines like the T series, not `sun4u` machines like Enterprise M4000 (https://oss.oracle.com/linux-sparc/docs/RELEASE-NOTES-1.0-en.html); however I don't know what might have changed between that release and the more recent "Oracle Linux for SPARC" releases